# Getting error to display dashboard page in PHP LARAVEL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

**I am getting this error:**

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
file_get_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied (View: C:\Users\RudraSimha\Desktop\mailer\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)
```

**Previous exceptions:**

```
file_get_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied (0)
```

Error show at the below line:

```
$series = file_get_contents($this->file);
```

from app\Library\QuotaTrackerFile.php file that contain:

```
            $this->hasLock = false;
            flock($reader, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
            fclose($reader);

            break;
        }

        // Otherwise, loop and wait to for the lock
    }
}

/**
 * Load time series from file.
 *
 * @return array time series
 */
private function load()
{
    $series = file_get_contents($this->file);
    preg_match('/(?<archived>^[^\|]{1,24})\|/', $series, $matched);
    if (array_key_exists('archived', $matched)) {
        $this->archived = array_map('intval', explode(':', $matched['archived'])); // [ $start, $value]
    } else {
        $this->archived = [null, 0];
    }

    // @note the method below is deprecated as it is quite slow
    //     return array_map('intval', array_values(array_filter(explode(',', file_get_contents($this->file)))));
    // a faster way is to use json_decode

    // REXP to replace anything before the pipe or leading/trailing comma
    $this->series = json_decode('['.preg_replace('/(^(.*\|,*|,+)|,+$)/', '', $series).']');

    return $this->series;
}

/**
 * Time out a lock request when it exceeds the QUOTA setting.
 */
```

```
Arguments
"file_get_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied (View: C:\Users\RudraSimha\Desktop\mailer\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)"
```

Comment: check the owner/group of your files through your entire project, especially in templates folder

Comment: For Windows, wrap the file in a `.bat` file or for linux in a `.sh` file. Then OSes would associate it with an executable script.